# Does CartThrob allow multiple carts?

Tags: cartthrob

Does CartThrob allow multiple carts? Is it possible to have 2 unique carts? 1 is a standard cart.  1 is a **custom gift box** cart — customers will fill up this cart with products that they are sending as a **custom gift boxes** to someone. We don't want to use 1 cart because then we have to deal with multiple shipping addresses and we want these **custom gift box orders** to be made up of individual product SKUs from our product catalog. LemonStand uses [cart_name](http://lemonstand.com/api/class/shop_cartitem/#cart_name-property) for cart assignment.

Answer (score 1):

No it does not allow multiple carts.

Great feature request though.